# GLKits equivalent for CreateFromVectors()

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, glkit, quaternions

I would like to know what (if there is) is the equivalent of CreateFromVectors() for GLKit. I can't see that idea being left out since it plays such a great feature in 3D graphical programming. I'm trying to convert the following to Objective-C from C++ and cannot touch upon C++ for this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
m_animation.End = Quaternion::CreateFromVectors(vec3(0, 1, 0), direction);
```

AKA:

```
inline QuaternionT<T> QuaternionT<T>::CreateFromVectors(const Vector3<T>& v0, const Vector3<T>& v1)
{
    if (v0 == -v1)
        return QuaternionT<T>::CreateFromAxisAngle(vec3(1, 0, 0), Pi);

    Vector3<T> c = v0.Cross(v1);
    T d = v0.Dot(v1);
    T s = std::sqrt((1 + d) * 2);

    QuaternionT<T> q;
    q.x = c.x / s;
    q.y = c.y / s;
    q.z = c.z / s;
    q.w = s / 2.0f;
    return q;
}
```

I would also like to know how to translate:

```
mat4 rotation(m_animation.Current.ToMatrix());
glMultMatrixf(rotation.Pointer());
```

With ToMatrix() being:

```
inline Matrix3<T> QuaternionT<T>::ToMatrix() const
{
    const T s = 2;
    T xs, ys, zs;
    T wx, wy, wz;
    T xx, xy, xz;
    T yy, yz, zz;
    xs = x * s;  ys = y * s;  zs = z * s;
    wx = w * xs; wy = w * ys; wz = w * zs;
    xx = x * xs; xy = x * ys; xz = x * zs;
    yy = y * ys; yz = y * zs; zz = z * zs;
    Matrix3<T> m;
    m.x.x = 1 - (yy + zz); m.y.x = xy - wz;  m.z.x = xz + wy;
    m.x.y = xy + wz; m.y.y = 1 - (xx + zz); m.z.y = yz - wx;
    m.x.z = xz - wy; m.y.z = yz + wx;  m.z.z = 1 - (xx + yy);
    return m;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar in the classes for C++ on the back end and am not sure how they would translate over.

Comment: My personal goal is to translate this into pure objective c / c. Long story and the rest of the reasoning put aside, I don't want to use c++ at all. Not because I can't, but because I don't want to. It also has to do with optimization a for ios development alongside further understanding of working with GLKit.

Comment: Then GLKQuaternion is your friend.  It's not the prettiest or most useful of structures, but the concept is the same.

Comment: That I know, but I couldn't find a single method for GLKQuaternion that would create a Quaternion from two GLKVector3 arguments. That more or less what I'm looking for, the best way to translate the above for GLKit.